# Expected begin on if condition

Tags: inno-setup

I get `Expected Begin` on the first line:

```
if ActiveLanguage = 'English' then
 begin
  // create the product key page
  PkeyPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
      'Type your product key', '',
      'You can find the {#SetupSetting("AppName")} product key in the email we sent you. Activation will register the product key to this computer.');
  PkeyPage.Add('Product Key:', False);
end;
else
   if ActiveLanguage = 'Italian' then

      //create the product key page
      PkeyPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
          'Inserisci il codice di attivazione', '',
          'Puoi trovare il codice di attivazione di {#SetupSetting("AppName")} nell''email ricevuta dopo l''acquisto. L''attivazione registrerà il programma sul tuo PC.');
      PkeyPage.Add('Product Key:', False);
end;
```

I'm trying to display different message box based on the language choosed in the installer

Comment: I think it should be begin .... end else begin ... end;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Else) you can see the syntax:

```
if boolean_condition then
    begin
      statement_one;
      statement_two;
    end 
  else
    begin
      statement_three;
      statement_four;
    end;
```

Change `end; else` to `end else begin`.